# Geofence client side error when allowed area is defined for layer in own workspace

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-geofence

Geoserver & Geofence version: 2.16.0, Windows 10, JDK1.8.0_131.

I'm learning to set allowed area to Geofence Data Rule in Geoserver 2.16.0 and I hit a client side error when allowed area is defined for layer in my own workspace.

If I add data rule with allowed area defined for layer from any of the sample workspace from geoserver installation (nurc/tiger etc), I get correct result when I preview the layer. But when I add data rule with allowed area for any layer from my own workspace I get error at client side (web browser) when I preview layer. There is no error at the server side when this client side error happened.

There is no client side error if the allowed area of the same data rule is cleared. Therefore I think the error is caused by allowed area.

I used the platform independent binary for geoserver, and extracted the Geofence Server extension (geoserver-2.16.0-geofence-server-plugin.zip) to the \WEB-INF\lib directory. Not sure if other extension is required. Using the H2 db that came with Geofence. The datasource of my workspace is connected to PostGIS.

The client side error:

```
 org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this container for rendering: [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = listContainer]]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1848)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3916)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1836)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3916)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1836)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3916)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:801)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalPrepareForRender(Component.java:2236)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.internalPrepareForRender(Page.java:242)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2325)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reproject the restricted area to the layer's native SRS
    at org.geoserver.geofence.GeofenceAccessManager.buildAccessLimits(GeofenceAccessManager.java:435)
    at org.geoserver.geofence.GeofenceAccessManager.getAccessLimits(GeofenceAccessManager.java:351)
    at org.geoserver.geofence.GeofenceAccessManager.getAccessLimits(GeofenceAccessManager.java:268)
    at org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager.getAccessLimits(ResourceAccessManager.java:47)
    at org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManagerWrapper.getAccessLimits(ResourceAccessManagerWrapper.java:225)
    at org.geoserver.security.CatalogFilterAccessManager.getAccessLimits(CatalogFilterAccessManager.java:63)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.buildWrapperPolicy(SecureCatalogImpl.java:893)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.buildWrapperPolicy(SecureCatalogImpl.java:837)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:617)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:507)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl$2.apply(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1539)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl$2.apply(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1535)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:785)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.util.CloseableIteratorAdapter.next(CloseableIteratorAdapter.java:56)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.computeNext(Iterators.java:638)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.util.CloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNext(CloseableIteratorAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:42)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.util.CloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNext(CloseableIteratorAdapter.java:46)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.web.demo.PreviewLayerProvider.filteredItems(PreviewLayerProvider.java:193)
    at org.geoserver.web.demo.PreviewLayerProvider.iterator(PreviewLayerProvider.java:154)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataViewBase$ModelIterator.<init>(DataViewBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataViewBase.getItemModels(DataViewBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getItemModels(AbstractPageableView.java:101)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView.onPopulate(RefreshingView.java:93)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.onBeforeRender(AbstractPageableView.java:115)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:950)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1836)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 311040°00.0'N is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:894)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:940)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:109)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.projectCoordinateSequence(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:275)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformStraightLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:221)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:200)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformPolygon(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:283)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:163)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS.transform(JTS.java:450)
    at org.geoserver.geofence.GeofenceAccessManager.buildAccessLimits(GeofenceAccessManager.java:429)
    ... 163 more
```

The native srs and declared srs of my layer are both EPSG:3857:

[image: srs in geoserver]

The srid in database table is 3857:

[image: The crs in database table is 3857]

I do not know why I get

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reproject the restricted area to
>   the layer's native SRS

and

> org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException:
>   Latitude 311040°00.0'N is too close to a pole

That latitude is supposed to be in meter and I have no idea where the value *311040* is coming from, it's not in my config and no data with that coordinate.

I tested several geoserver & geofence versions from 2.15.0 to 2.16.0, same error.

I couldn't find useful information from Geofence documentation, and couldn't find similar error through duckduckgo or google.

Anyone know what are the possible cause of this error?

Comment: GeoServer thinks that one of your layers is not in 3857 - check the **native** projections

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for your response. I added screen shots to my question. In db and layer all srs are 3857.

Comment: what about inside GeoFence - that is where the error is coming from

Comment: There's no error inside geofence (server side). I'm not sure whether there's additional configuration required in geoserver or geofence. Geofence documentations are outdated. Test connection in geofence is successful. Allowed area using sample workspaces are working correctly.

Comment: Although there's no error at server when the above error occurred, there's an error reading the `geofence-default-override.properties` file in `gs-geofence-server-2.16.0.jar` during GS startup. Also, whenever a user login to geoserver admin page, there's a warning  `WARN [geofence.cache] - org.geoserver.geofence.cache.CachedRuleReader$NoAuthException: Can't auth user [<username>]` . When non-admin user login from a different computer (not localhost) there's a `ERROR [util.FilterUtils] - Bad address filter <IP address>`, but the IP address is included in Authentication. Are they related?

Comment: @WenPing Have you got solution to this issue?